# Excel cascading list for all rows

Tags: list, excel-2016, cascading

I try to apply a cascading list for all rows in an Excel file.

I have this countries and cities datas:

[datas with lists names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ9mD.png)

And did the usual cascade listing with the INDIRECT function for the first row:

[cascading list for row 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pscm9.png)

Now I want to do the same for row 3 to 1'000: having the list of "countries" in column A, and the related cities in column B. How can I automatize this operation?

I tried the datas validation with this "  =indirect($A:$A)  " but the list doesn't show up.

Comment: What have you tried? And how is it not working as you expected? Please add this to your original question.

Comment: I edited my question, hope this will help!